# Why scroll top is needed after action submit for Struts2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url

Why screen scrolls down when page is rendered by struts2 action (Context: response from the server, equivalent jsp page rendered from sturts action).

This question has a reference to question asked here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8181413/5086633

Here the solution given is to use this function

```
document.getElementById("idofyourdivhere").scrollIntoView(true);
```

However, for me the generated html page has lot of top level div which cannot be picked as explained above. I am left with this option to scroll to the top of the page (scroll top) after the page gets rendered. I just want to get rid of both, is there anyway to stop doing that and fix the same in the struts2 action/configuration itself ? I am preferably looking for a struts2 fix for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you perform a standard submit, and you land in the middle of the page, it means that in your URL you have something like:

> www.blabla.com/foo/bar**#someID**

, where `#someID` tells the browser to look for an object with `id="someID"` and scroll to it.

This mechanism can be originated

- **server side**, by returning an URL with the fragment at the end, or
- **client side**, with a javascript block executed on document ready, most likely through the usage of HTML5 `replaceState()` / `pushState()` APIs...

**The cleanest solution is to remove this unwanted behavior at the source** but, if for some reason you can't, you can do it client side like follows:

```
$(function(){ // On document ready
    if ((hashPos = location.href.indexOf("#")) > 0){ // if there's an hash
        history.replaceState("","",location.href.substring(0,hashPos)); // strip that part
        window.scrollTo(0, 0); // and manually scroll up (first time only)
    }
});
```

This will turn

> www.blabla.com/foo/bar#someID

into

> www.blabla.com/foo/bar

dynamically.